# viewer v7 performance regression

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Did anyone else notice graphic regression in the new v7 of the autodesk forge viewer? The new features like ambient shadows look nice, but the basic viewer has worse output in terms of navigation. I have some samples here comparing v6 to v7 with most graphic features turned off and progressive display and smooth navigation turned on.

- [v6, only distant objects disappear](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xafw4qmhLTKXhu4Ecou3kbXSpoGJ3dl_)
- [v7, almost all models disappear, this even happens without smooth navigation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xIx2JVcXB9bV-j4C43n45F0g9fNvelS1)
- [v6, orbiting doesn't turn models inside out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sDvsX7xwlxeXvAXA1R4avzg80c0gac3C)
- [v7, orbiting does turn models inside out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=128FygrI4Efehu7LjB_gVkbVlfLD-LLYf)
- [v7, the disappearing models makes it the easing of the zoom pretty annoying, since it only shows objects if the camera has completely stopped moving](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1725x3fzbh9UWMh24QxN8xEwuAgXPbjlS)

I can see the progressive display hiding as a potential feature, but I wonder is there a treshold or depth where progressive display will hide meshes that is can configurable? The flipping of mesh normals seems more like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The progressive display can only be turned on/off. There's no granular level of control, unfortunately.

The progressive rendering is driven by a hard-coded "frame budget", where the viewer tries to render as much content as possible within the given number of milliseconds. It's possible that v7 introduces shader/rendering changes that affect the amount of geometry that can be rendered within the same budget. And as far as the inverted normals, that does look like a bug. Let me report your observations to the dev team to get more details on that.